# Text Attributes (underscore, grid etc.) don't work on my own handle

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-studio-2019

I have a problem about text attributes in a my C++ program. The problem is that: if I set `0x0F` (white) as attribute, the program works, but, if I set `0x0F | COMMON_LVB_UNDERSCORE`, the program set only the colour. I want to create a *library* for console called CLib using Windows API. I think the problem is that I used a no-standard handle as console handle so could I miss any access attribute?
The next is the code of handle creation:

```
[Console.cpp]
Bool Console::create()
{
    if (!mConsole)
    {
        mConsole = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(
            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
            FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
            NULL,
            CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER,
            NULL
        );
        return (Bool)mConsole;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Where `typedef bool Bool;` and

```
[Console.hpp]
class Console {
public:
    // code
private:
    // code
    static HANDLE mConsole;
}
```

That I defined at the top of Console.cpp file as `HANDLE Console::mConsole = NULL;`.
The fun thing is that console is painted by program but other attributes are ignored. At this point I think that the real problem isn't handle but something (as a conversion) in other files.

I want to ask you if do `SetConsoleTextAttributes(HANDLE handle, DWORD attributes)` function set attributes only on standard handles? (if not I will share the whole code to understand the problem)
I say this because if I write `SetConsoleTextAttributes(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), same_attributes)` works!

I wish to send the whole code but it is very long... there are a lot of files...

Ok, thanks to tips. I create 2 short files to explain the problem in well way ;).
Sorry for Bool re-definition, but I follow the Windows style to redefine all types (these files use only 1 re-definition, is it ok? :P).

```
[Problem.hpp]
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::wstring String;

struct RectInt
{
    COORD size;
    COORD position;
};

BOOL WINAPI ConsoleHandler(DWORD ctrltype);

COORD getCursorPosition(HANDLE handle);

class Console
{
public:

    Console(const String& title, const RectInt& rect)
    {
        this->create(rect);
        SetConsoleTitleW(title.c_str());
    }

    ~Console()
    {
        this->free();
        CloseHandle(mConsole);
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // the problem is when I call thisConsole function
    bool setAttributes(const DWORD& attributes)
    {
        mAttributes = attributes;
        return SetConsoleTextAttribute(mConsole, mAttributes);
    }
    bool setCursorPosition(const COORD& position)
    {
        return SetConsoleCursorPosition(mConsole, position);
    }
    bool setRect(const RectInt& rect)
    {
        mRect = rect;
        SMALL_RECT windowInfo =
        {
            mRect.position.X,
            mRect.position.Y,
            mRect.size.X,
            mRect.size.Y
        };
        return SetConsoleWindowInfo(mConsole, true, &windowInfo);
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    bool allocate() { return AllocConsole(); }
    bool flush()
    {
        if (!SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(mConsole)) return false;
        return FlushConsoleInputBuffer(mConsole);
    }
    bool clear(const DWORD& attributes = 0x0F)
    {
        CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO info;
        DWORD count;

        if (!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(mConsole, &info)) return false;
        if (!this->paint(attributes)) return false;

        if (!FillConsoleOutputCharacter(
            mConsole,
            L' ',
            info.dwSize.X * info.dwSize.Y,
            { 0,0 },
            &count
        )) return false;

        if (!FillConsoleOutputAttribute(
            mConsole,
            info.wAttributes,
            info.dwSize.X * info.dwSize.Y,
            { 0,0 },
            &count
        )) return false;

        if (!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(mConsole, &info)) return false;
        return this->setCursorPosition(mRect.position);
    }
    bool free() { return FreeConsole(); }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    bool write(const String& text, const bool& flush = false)
    {
        if (!this->setCursorPosition(getCursorPosition(mConsole))) return false;
        DWORD charsWritten = 0;
        if (!WriteConsoleW(mConsole, text.c_str(), text.size(), &charsWritten, NULL)) return false;

        if (flush) return this->flush();
        return true;
    }

protected:

    bool create()
    {
        if (!mConsole)
        {
            mConsole = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(
                GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                NULL,
                CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER,
                NULL
            );
            return (bool)mConsole;
        }
        return true;
    }
    bool create(const RectInt& rect)
    {
        if (!this->allocate())
        {
            FreeConsole();
            if (!this->allocate()) return false;
        }
        if (!this->create()) return false;

        if (!SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(
            mConsole,
            { rect.size.X, rect.size.Y }
        )) return false;

        if (!this->setRect(rect)) return false;
        if (!SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ConsoleHandler, true)) return false;

        if (!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(mConsole, &mBufferInfo)) return false;

        if (!SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(mConsole)) return false;

        if (!this->setAttributes(0x0F)) return false;
        return this->clear(mAttributes);
    }

private:

    static HANDLE mConsole;

    DWORD mAttributes;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO mBufferInfo;
    RectInt mRect;
};
```

and the main file:

```
[Problem.cpp]
#include "Problem.hpp"
HANDLE Console::mConsole = nullptr;

BOOL WINAPI ConsoleHandler(DWORD ctrltype)
{
    return true;
}

COORD getCursorPosition(HANDLE handle)
{
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO info;
    if (GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(handle, &info)) return info.dwCursorPosition;
    return { 0,0 };
}

int main()
{
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///                 Output (Standard)                   ///
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 0xF3 | COMMON_LVB_UNDERSCORE);

    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl; //< print "Hello World!" on console with new attributes console attributes 
                                              // (0xF3 | COMMAND_LVB_UNDERSCORE)

    system("pause");

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///         Output (using Console class)                ///
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // constructor passing title of console and rectangle (size,position)
    Console console(L"CLibTest", RectInt({ { 200,200 },{ 0,0 } }));

    console.setAttributes(0xF3 | COMMON_LVB_UNDERSCORE); //< do anything!!!! <- PROBLEM
    console.write(L"Hello World!\n", true); //< print "Hello World!" on console with default console attributes (0x0F)

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //std::cin.get(); //< to block automatically close ;)
    return 0;
}
```

I hope that now is more complete.

Comment: You're correct, don't send all the code. But you should make a small program which **only** shows the problem. No more, no less. A lot of people here have VS2019, they should be able to copy-paste your small program, hit F5-Run and see the problem themselves.

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, I doubt that your library will find lots of fans as long as your interface uses an invented `Bool` type. We already have `bool`, so that you don't have to reinvent a boolean type.

Comment: Please make sure your [mcve] is minimal. We don't need to see your entire `Console` class, nor does it help us read the code when abstractions are involved. Abstractions are great for production code, but for a [mcve] they only add distractions.

Comment: Ilnspectable thanks for your suggestion but I have already read that tip. This isn't the full code (it is composed by 15 files .hpp and more). I wanted to paste this code because you can see what each method does, maybe I can make a mistake in one of these methods (that are the main). However, if you want I can reduce in other file the essential things ;-).

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. Two console windows are created. The first shows black text on a white background, then the "pause" command is issued before a second window is created, painted in the same manner and destroyed, then the IDE awaits a keypress to return. (The program's already ended). If the call to `console.setAttributes` is commented-out, one gets the standard white text on a black background in the second window. Clearly, the line you've indicated as not working, _is_ working. Perhaps it's not doing what you'd like, but the same attributes produce the same output. :consfused:

Comment: Sorry, I wrote _do anything_ but isn't correct because the program paints text with passed colour but if you see well you can view that I passed also the underscore attribute but this is ignoring by console... maybe there is my error but sure what I see is different in both consoles, passing the same attributes. In standard console text is underlined and painted in the next console it is only painted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works for me. Can you have a try?

```
CHAR data[] = "hello world\n";
DWORD writeBytes = 0;
HANDLE mConsole;

mConsole = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    NULL,
    CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER,
    NULL
);

SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(mConsole);

WriteConsoleA(mConsole, data, sizeof(data), &writeBytes, NULL);

DWORD mAttributes = 0x0F | COMMON_LVB_UNDERSCORE;
if (!SetConsoleTextAttribute(mConsole, mAttributes))
{
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("SetConsoleTextAttribute"),
        TEXT("Console Error"), MB_OK);
    return 1;
}

WriteConsoleA(mConsole, data, sizeof(data), &writeBytes, NULL);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks when I can, I try your code and check if my code doesn't work at the same way.

Comment: @Andrea477 OK. Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Your code works thanks...now I must insert your code with Console class, probably the problem was a conversion between integers types that I passed. I wish it is that. However now all works so thanks! ;-)